# Searching for Webpack config for React Components Library with Typescript, SASS & CSS Modules via SASS support

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

Like the title says I'm searching for a working Webpack config for a React Components Library with support for Typescript, SASS and CSS Modules via SASS. I would really appreciate if somebody has one and would like to share it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Install dev dependency

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server typescript ts-loader style-loader css-loader sass-loader --save-dev
```

Then create webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/app.ts'),
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: __dirname
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This config works. Also I was using the wrong webpack config in my project the whole time (I have mutliple).